# Can't use interstitial admob in react native bare expo workflow

Tags: admob, expo, react-native

I have an intertistial admob that used to work on expo normal workflow but now that I switched to bare doesn't appears and throws the warning

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

I already looked up the additional steps for bare workflow in the expo admob installation and it all checked right.

The ad banners work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an app in my phone that works as a firewall and wasn't yet authorizing traffic needed for the ad from my bare compiled app. I authorized it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

**For Future Readers::**

use this callback in ad component and check its response code and verify using given link or bullet points

```
onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError
```

See its response from **[google's ad events](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#ad_events)**

- **ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR** - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
- **ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST** - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
- **ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR** - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.
- **ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL** - The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

options in admob to check

[image]